# Encrypt Document Field in Mongo Shell

Tags: mongodb, shell, encryption

When inserting data via the Mongo shell, is there a way to encrypt or hash the data? I do not need to encrypt the whole database or collection, just a field in a document.

I know I can do this via an application and encrypt the value before inserting it to the database, but i'm not sure what to do when entering the data manually via the Mongo shell.

A javascript solution will work too ... any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongo doesn't support field level encryption. 
Server side javasript function need to be called on every read/write as there is no `triggers`.

So the best way to have that done is shift this to application, as will not add extra load to db engine.

The other thing to solve: search will be unavailable on encrypted value.
And finally you need to deploy safe way to manage encryption keys.